# Error When load Table Progress Openedge in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, openedge, progress-db, powerbi-datasource

Im very newbie in Power BI.

I try to connect Progress Opendedge to Power BI using ODBC.

ODBC success connect, I try Via excel success to show record.

But in Power BI, when i try to load table i've got error.

```
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement
```

Please Help and give me advice.

Thanks before,

Comment: You should provide more details about the problem. Like, which query is causing the error, what version of OE, what things you have tried etc. It is very hard to understand the problem from the vague details provided.

Comment: Openedge Version 11.3. I haven't query, only at the stage select table. My table is appear but when im selected, i;ve got error. 

I try to use Qlick View, running well in Qlick View. But Error in Power BI

Comment: The error says that there is a syntax problem with your SQL statement...  post the SQL and we might be able to help.   Refuse to post the SQL and you will be waiting a long time for answers

Comment: Thx tom.. but im not use sql statement. If u ever use power bi. U just click the table. Before i ask i already read this post http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000032174.  In that article i must remove the senicolon, But until now idk where i must to remove that

Answer (score 0):

I've Found that solution. Can't use Drag and drop table in Power BI with openedge Data source. 
But use advance editor to manual query.